# How to run an XMLRPC server and an XMLRPC client on Mininet hosts through a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, xml-rpc, mininet

I am trying to run an XMLRPC server and an XMLRPC client on Mininet hosts, using the script below.

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import OVSController


class MyTopo(Topo):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__(self)

        # Add hosts
        server1 = self.addHost('server1')
        server2 = self.addHost('server2')

        # Add switch
        s1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        # Add links
        self.addLink(server1, s1)
        self.addLink(server2, s1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Mininet(topo=MyTopo(), controller=OVSController)
    net.start()
    print(net.hosts[0].cmd('python3 xmlrpc_server.py'))
    print(net.hosts[1].cmd('python3 xmlrpc_client.py'))
```

The file **xmlrpc_server.py** is:

```
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import threading


def is_even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 8000), logRequests=True, allow_none = True)
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
print("Listening on port 8000...")
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.start()
```

The file **xmlrpc_client.py** is:

```
import xmlrpc.client


proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://10.0.0.1:8000/")
print("3 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(3)))
print("100 is even: %s" % str(proxy.is_even(100)))
```

The problem is that although I have used a thread, when I run the xmlrpc_server.py script on server1, the execution pauses at line `server_thread.start()` waiting for the script execution to be completed before moving on and thus never goes on to the next line, which means that the XMLRPC client script never runs. How do I overcome this problem?

P.S.: xmlrpc_server.py and xmlrpc_client.py can be executed through the server terminals (by using the commands `xterm server1` and `xterm server2` on Mininet CLI and then using the commands `python3 xmlrpc_server.py` and `python3 xmlrpc_client.py` on the xterm terminals that open), but I need to start the server and client through a python script so as to perform some further calculations after the communication between the two servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `print(net.hosts[0].cmd('python3 xmlrpc_server.py'))` with `print(net.hosts[0].sendCmd('python3 xmlrpc_server.py'))`. Connection is sometimes refused, but that issue can be resolved with exception handling on the client script.